# Обводка вокруг img

Tags: css3

При зажатии лкм на картинку и отведении указателя мыши всторону после чего отпускания лкм вокруг картинки появляется штрихованная обводка. Картинку отображаю через img src=""

Вот видео после каких действий и что появляется: https://youtu.be/NmmtYsur69I

Каким правилом css можно убрать это?

Вот скрин:

[image]

Извините за плохое качество видео, сейчас перезапишу с лучшими настройками(и да в том видео должно быть можно включить 480p)

---

Вот код

```css
html {
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #181f4b;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #969dcd;
}

img.unselectable {
 outline: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c58dd, #2a44c8);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
 width: 40px;
}

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: rgb(59,173,227);
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
 <link href="css/reset.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/main.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/adaptive.css"   rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/tooltip.css"   rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/range.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- <link href="css/slider.css"   rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
     <img class="unselectable" src="/images/logo.png">
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Установите в стилях для этой картинки -  `outline:none;`

Comment: outline: none; установил, не убралось

Comment: обновил ссылку на видео в лучшем качестве (1080p)

Comment: лучше конечно воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Добавлен код выше

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего поможет

```
outline: none
```

Comment: Установил не помогло, сейчас скину код